# How to find the indexes of items in a list of lists (python)?

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
list1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

And I have this other list of lists with the items from list1:

```
list2 = [[a, c], [d,e,f], [g]]
```

and I want to know the indices in list1 in the same order as in list 2:

```
indexes = [[0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If so, please provide us with your attempt here. If not, go ahead and give it your best shot. We can help if you have specific implementation questions, but we won't write code for you!

Comment: Hi! On Stack Overflow we expect you to show us what you have tried before. We are *not* here to do all the work from scratch. Ideally, we take a look at the code that you have already tried and then point out the issues. That's easier for us, and it will help you to become a better programmer by understanding issues you ran into rather than using someone else's code.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
indexes = [[list1.index(k) for k in i] for i in list2]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[[0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following list comprehension, where the indices where the values match can be obtained by using `enumerate` while iterating over `list1`:

```
[[ix for j in i for ix,k in enumerate(list1) if k==j] for i in list2]
# [[0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```

---

Some reads you might find useful:

- [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Answer (score 1):

An efficient approach is to use a dict comprehension to create a mapping that maps items to indices with `enumerate`, and then use a list comprehension to map items in the sub-lists to the indices according to the mapping dict:

```
d = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(list1)}
[list(map(d.get, l)) for l in list2]
```

This returns:

```
[[0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```